# Jobtracker is not up

Tags: hadoop

I have installed hadoop on centos. I have modified host name to slave2. I have also modified 
core-site.xml, mapred files.but job tracker , Data node and task tracker are not starting. Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

Check your daemon logs. They should point you to where the problem is.

When you start hadoop, you see messages like this:

```
starting tasktracker, logging to /home/username/hadoop/logs/hadoop-user-tasktracker-user-desktop.out
```

Open the .log file, it should give you a clue.